# Decoding only one specific slice using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a hevc all-intra bitstream in which each frame has 4(2x2) tiles(slices). My program can decode it using ffmpeg and render it using OpenGL. The decoding process is almost the same as this example. http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/decode__video_8c_source.html;

What I want is only one specific tile in each frame (for example, the second tile); I don't want to decode the other 3 tiles to reduce the decoder load.
If it is possible to decode only one specific tile(slice), please teach me how to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps this is not the best place to ask such question. You might consider asking at the ffmpeg mailing list like [libav-user](https://ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/libav-user).

Comment: Thank you Mark. I subscribed to the mailing list and posted.

Comment: Has there been any progress? If you are ok with gpac (it seems to offer CLI tools mainly, though), I guess similar things can be achieved. ([link](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/HEVC-Tile-based-adaptation-guide#packaging-your-video))